# Interfaz gráfica java en una raspberry pi b+ con pantalla LCD 3.5"

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, raspberry-pi

Tengo un proyecto en el cual debo realizar una interfaz gráfica que controle los usuarios de un servidor radius; la aplicación debe correrse en una raspberry pi b+ y mostrando en una pantalla táctil que he conseeguido 3.5"(http://la-fabrica.com.ar/display/1475-pantalla-tactil-35p-xpt2046-para-raspberry-display-con-gabinete-acrilico.html).

La cuestión es que al momento de ejecutar la interfaz gráfica, especificamente un jframe, por hdmi se ejecuta normal, pero al momento de cambiar a la pantalla táctil se muestra solo una ventana morada sin mostrarme nada de la interfaz.

En java estoy trabajando como si estuviera haciendo una aplicación normal para Windows o Linux basándome en la JVM.

En programación he cambiado...

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) { //Metal, Nimbus
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());`
```

Pero no me ha funcionado.

[image: Adjunto una imagen del recuadro morado que me presenta en lugar de la interfaz.]

Comment: te dejo esto link que hablan de eso: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7137

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero si funciona correctamente el sistema raspberry tanto en hdmi como en la pantalla LCD, solo que mi programa java no se logra visualizar en la pantalla LCD.

Comment: Encontre algo quizas te pueda ayudar pero es para Windows pero quizas puedas estrapolar la logica para java en tu sistema op. En windows en el archivo java.exe y javaw.exe si con el boton derecho vas a las propiedades del archivo hay un tab que se llama compatibilidad ahi podes decirle que se ejecute con 256 colores o pantallas de resoluciones bajas. Quizas por ahi pase el problema.

Comment: Gracias a todos, son íncreibles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola amigo su problema se debe a la versión de OpenJdk que estás utilizando Seguramente tienes instalada la versión 11, lo que debes hacer es instalar la versión OpenJdk Java 8 para eso debes ingresar los siguientes comandos:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Despues de esto debes establecer el OpenJdk 8  como la version predeterminada del sistema, para esto debes ingresar el siguiente comando

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

[image: Seleccionar el jdk por defecto]

Escribe el numero que corresponda a la versión de OpenJdk8 (el asterisco representa la version selecionada actualmente en el sistema).en mi caso la versión OpenJDK8 es el número 2 y presiona Enter

Después de esto ejecuta nuevamente tu aplicación java y me cuentas. Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Wow... era eso. Muchísimas gracias amigo, eres un pro :D

Comment: De nada amigo fué un gusto ayudarte  :D. Puedes votar que mi respuesta te ha sido útil por favor?

Comment: @luisGutierrez Si te has basado en esta respuesta para solucionar tu problema, lo correcto es marcarla como `usada`. Para ello, tienes el icono del *check* ( `✓` ) situado a su izquierda. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo amigo. Perdón, pero soy nuevo. Ya le he dado al check. Muchas Gracias.